# Not hitting error page on ASP.NET 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm playing with a new ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 app. So far, it's an empty, out-of-the-box application Visual Studio creates when ASP.NET 5 MVC project is selected.

In the Home controller action, I added the line to see if I'd get redirected to the generic error page i.e. ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml

```
throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Test exception!");
```

When I run the project, all I get is an exception in my code but don't get redirected to the error page.

The following is the standard Startup.cs -- again, out-of-the-box code. I didn't make any changes yet.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Shouldn't I get redirected to the error page?

Comment: Where are you running your application? On developer environment or otherwise?

Comment: It's currently showing "Development" when I go to Properties and select Debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's deconstruct the interesting bits (I removed irrelevant code):

```
if (env.IsDevelopment()) 
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

The first one is `IsDevelopment()`. How does the CLR knows? Well... there's an environment variable named `ASPNET_ENV` that is set when you do `F5` in Visual Studio. It will automatically set it to `Development` and it will then show you a very nice stack trace just like `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` used to do.

What happens if you are running this from a basic command line you say? Well the default value will be `Production` (or `!IsDevelopment()` if you wish) and suddenly `UseExceptionHandler(...)` will be used.

It is at that moment that the redirection will happens.

#### Conclusion

Visual Studio will run your application in `Development` mode automatically.

Running the application independently will default to `Production`.

You can redefine this value by setting `ASPNET_ENV` in your environment variables. It can be anything and the only value that will affect this code is `Development`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are executing this via DNX via cmd, which will set `ASPNET_ENV` to *Production*, rather than *Development*.

I like to log the environment name on startup to help debug this type of scenario;

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup")                     // add
        .LogInformation($"Startup: {env.EnvironmentName}");   // this

    ...
}
```

Otherwise you could stick a breakpoint on `if (env.IsDevelopment())` to make sure you're hitting it.  If you run the project in VS2015, it will run as *Development*, however, if you run it via DNX on the command prompt, you'll need to set the `ASPNET_ENV` environment variable to *Development*.

Answer (score 0):

In no way is this the recommended way to achieve this but you could use:

```
     if (app.WebRootPath.Contains("Development"))
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
```

This checks the file path where you have stored your web application for the word 'Development' and applies the settings accordingly, you could use method to force an environment change (as long as your web root is set up correctly).

More more info, look at this link:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/02/01/an-update-on-asp-net-core-and-net-core/
and this:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html

RC2 is changing some fundamental things about deployment and hosting, so it might be worth reading up on them now before you get yourself to far down a path?